# RuntimeError: _th_normal not supported on CPUType for Long

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, normal-distribution

I am trying to generate a number from the normal distribution using:

```
from torch.distributions import Normal
noise = Normal(th.tensor([0]), th.tensor(3.20))
noise = noise.sample()
```

But I am getting this error: `RuntimeError: _th_normal not supported on CPUType for Long`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first tensor `th.tensor([0])` **is of `torch.Long` type** due to automatic type inference from passed value while `float` or `FloatTensor` is required by function.

You can solve it by passing `0.0` explicitly like this:

```
import torch

noise = torch.distributions.Normal(torch.tensor([0.0]), torch.tensor(3.20))
noise = noise.sample()
```

Better yet, drop `torch.tensor` altogether, in this case Python types will be automatically casted to `float` if possible, so this is valid as well:

```
import torch

noise = torch.distributions.Normal(0, 3.20)
noise = noise.sample()
```

And please, do not alias `torch` as `th`, it is not official, use fully qualified name as this only confuses everyone.